# Averaging values pulled from sheets in an array

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to pull student scores from a sheet, average them for each student then output them to a new tab in the same sheet. Each student is scored by eight teachers on their character and leadership.

I am not a programer by trade so I'm learning as I go. I have figured out using the Google sheet scripting tool how to add the student and their scores into an array and output them to a new tab in sheets. I have found examples of code on how to average the numbers in an array but I haven't been able to get any of them to work. I'm assuming I need to add the code to average the values before doing the output, but all the examples I find seem to be in different programming languages than what sheets uses as I get errors when I put an any of the code I find. This is what I have working to get the students and the scores into a new tab.

```
function CharAvg(){

    var app = SpreadsheetApp;
    var sheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");

    var map = {};

    for(var row = 3; row <=297; row++)
    {
        var studentname = sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValues();

        if(studentname != " " && studentname != null && studentname != "")
        {
            if(!(studentname in map))
            {
                map[studentname] = [];
            }

            var character = sheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue();


            if(character != " " && character != null)
            {
                map[studentname].push(character);
            }

            var leadership = sheet.getRange(row, 5).getValue();

            if(leadership != " " && leadership != null)
            {
                map[studentname].push(leadership);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Browser.msgBox(studentname);
        }
    }

    var outputsheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet("OutPut");
    outputsheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue("Student Name");
    outputsheet.getRange(1, 2).setValue("Character Avg.");
    outputsheet.getRange(1, 3).setValue("Leadership Avg.");
    var row = 2;
    for (var studentname in map)
    {
        outputsheet.getRange(row, 1).setValue(studentname);

        for(var character in map[studentname])
        {

            outputsheet.getRange(row, 2).setValue(map[studentname][character]);
            for(var leadership in map[studentname])
            {
                outputsheet.getRange(row, 3).setValue(map[studentname][leadership]);
            }

            row ++
        }

        row ++
    }

}
```

If anyone could help me figure out how to do this in a Google sheet script it would make our lives easier. Otherwise we can get by writing a formula in the sheet manually to get the averages, but we would like to automate the process as much as possible. Thank you.

[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clqcr.png)

Answer (score 0):

I did not see where you are doing any averaging.  But this script does what I think you were trying to do.

```
function CharAvg() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet123");
  //var rg=sh.getRange(3,1,295,5);//This was your range
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());//this was for my data
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var sA=[];//student array
  var index=0;
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<vA[i].length;j++) {vA[i][j]=vA[i][j].toString().trim();}
    if(vA[i][1] && vA[i][2] && vA[i][4]) {
      sA.push({studentName:vA[i][1],character:vA[i][2],leadership:vA[i][4]});//each array element is an object  
    }else{
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Student Name: ' + vA[i][1]);
    }
  }
  //var osh=ss.insertSheet("outPut");//This was your output spelled differently
  var osh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet117');//This was for my data
  osh.appendRow(['Student Name','Character Avg','Leadership Avg']); //appending header
  for(var i=0;i<sA.length;i++) {
    osh.appendRow([sA[i].studentName,sA[i].character,sA[i].leadership]);//appending rows  
  }
}
```

My input sheet:

[image]

My output sheet:

[image]

> I presume that your data is already averaged because I didn't see any averaging process at all. This approach will run much faster because I just get data once and process it all in one array and then output the lines by appending them.

Does this look like the input data sheet

[image]

**Using the above table for input and the following code:**

## Calculating Student Averages

```
function CharAvg() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet118");
  //var rg=sh.getRange(3,1,295,5);//This was your range
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());//this was for my data
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var sA=[];//student array
  var sObj={sA:[]};
  var index=0;
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<vA[i].length;j++) {vA[i][j]=vA[i][j].toString().trim();}
    if(vA[i][1] && vA[i][2] && vA[i][4] && vA[i][5]) {
      if(sObj.hasOwnProperty(vA[i][1])) {
        sObj[vA[i][1]].character=Number(sObj[vA[i][1]].character)+Number(vA[i][2]);
        sObj[vA[i][1]].leadership=Number(sObj[vA[i][1]].leadership)+Number(vA[i][4]);
        sObj[vA[i][1]].submitted=Number(sObj[vA[i][1]].submitted)+Number(vA[i][5]);
        sObj[vA[i][1]].count++;
      }else{
        sObj[vA[i][1]]=new Score(vA[i][2],vA[i][4],vA[i][5]);
        sObj.sA.push(vA[i][1]);
      }

      sA.push({studentName:vA[i][1],character:vA[i][2],leadership:vA[i][4]});//each array element is an object  
    }else{
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Student Name: ' + vA[i][1]);
    }
  }
  var osh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet126');//This was for my data
  osh.clearContents();
  osh.appendRow(['Student Name','Character Avg','Leadership Avg','Submitted Avg','Count']); //appending header
  for(var i=0;i<sObj.sA.length;i++) {
    var row=[sObj.sA[i]].concat(sObj[sObj.sA[i]].row());
    osh.appendRow(row);
  }
}

function Score(character,leadership,submitted) {
  if(character && leadership && submitted) {
    this.character=character;
    this.leadership=leadership;
    this.submitted=submitted;
    this.count=1;
    this.characterAvg=function(){return Number(this.character)/Number(this.count);};
    this.leadershipAvg=function(){return Number(this.leadership)/Number(this.count);};
    this.submittedAvg=function(){return Number(this.submitted)/Number(this.count);};
    this.row=function(){return [this.characterAvg(),this.leadershipAvg(),this.submittedAvg(),this.count];}
  }
}
```

Table of Averages:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, the scores I have are not averaged in the sheet. The sheet I get is the scoring from the teachers. Each student gets ranked by 8 teachers, the code as I have it puts the students and their 8 scores for each category into an array and then it outputs it to a new sheet. The scores are not averaged yet, what I'm trying to do is average the 8 scores when they get pulled into the array. From what I've seen using reduce and a formula with it should work but I don't know where or how to insert it into the code I posted, if that makes any sense. Sorry like I said all this is new to me.

Comment: I didn't see anything about 8 scores for students.  Perhaps you can share some of your data with anonymous students.

Comment: By the way you should avoid using getValue() in loops.  It's much faster to get your data into an array with getValues() and operate solely from the array.  I'm talking speed improvements on the order 10X.

Comment: So the sheet I get is generated from responses to a Google form so the can come in a random order. This is also my first time using this site so I'm not sure how to add a table like you did. Looks something like this.                                                                                Student 1   3 3 Teacher 1
Student 2  3 4 Teacher 5
Student 7         3 2 Teacher 1
Student 1         3 3 Teacher 2
Student 1         4 4 Teacher 3
Student 27 4 5 Teacher 1
Student 2         4 5 Teacher 10
Thanks you so much for any help you can give.

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail. `Student 1 3 3 Teacher 1 Student 2 3 4 Teacher 5 Student 7 3 2 Teacher 1 Student 1 3 3 Teacher 2 Student 1 4 4 Teacher 3 Student 27 4 5 Teacher 1 Student 2 4 5 Teacher 10`

Comment: It would be students name, character score, leadership score, teacher submitting score. Each in their own column. But we don't care about which teacher is submitting the score we just want to take the student and the average score in each category.

Comment: So there would be a character score average, a leadership score average and a teacher submitting score average for each student. Is that correct. And also what columns are each of these fields located.

Comment: I assumed the positioning of all of the columns partially from your question and partially guessing.  But I can alway move the indices around if needed.  I added some averaging methods to the object constructor to reduce some of the clutter .

Comment: Hi Cooper, thanks for all the help. I've added a picture of what the input looks like with student names removed. We don't really care about the teacher or the comments just the scores in character and leadership and getting an average of each for each student. At this point we will just calculate things manually but thank you again for all the effort.